# Use shadowsocks qt5 in ubuntu can not connect

Tags: ubuntu

The log report like below:

```
Initialising ciphers...
RC4-MD5 (RC4-MD5) initialised.
Listen UDP socket state changed to QAbstractSocket::BoundState 
Running in local mode.
TCP server listen at port 1080
An invalid socket connection was rejected. Please make sure the connection type is SOCKS5.
An invalid socket connection was rejected. Please make sure the connection type is SOCKS5.
An invalid socket connection was rejected. Please make sure the connection type is SOCKS5.
```

How can I do?

Comment: I meet the same problem. I configure a socks5 proxy in NetworkManager. Chrome is able to use the proxy, but firefox not.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue.
After seeing the log

> An invalid socket connection was rejected. Please make sure the connection type is SOCKS5

I changed local server type from `SOCKS5` to `HTTP(S)`

And it works.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: I use AppImage of Shadowsocks-Qt5-3.0.0 on Linux Mint x64. Changing from SOCKS5 to HTTPS works. But isn't ss a SOCKS5 proxy? Is this a bug of Shadowsocks-Qt5 client?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried using shadowsocks on my Ubuntu 16.04, which didn't work (didn't really connect to my shadowsocks server, but did not throw any errors).

Client worked on my Android, Mac OSX and Windows, but not on Ubuntu.

I realized it wasn't shadowsocks issue, rather it wasn't issue at all: just system settings.

Solution that immediately worked (sslocal client immediately connected after that) was:

Go to **System Settings -> Network -> Network Proxy** and set Socks Host to `127.0.0.1` and port `1080` (these are settings for local host and local port I had set in `shadowsocks.json` configuration file).

Here it is: 
[image]

Immediately after that I could see connection log on my server's shadowsocks log. When I tested my IP in Chrome, it was my server's IP, and I could open sites that are blocked from my location.

Answer (score 0):

try `porxychains-ng`.

https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng

```
git clone git@github.com:rofl0r/proxychains-ng.git
cd proxychains-ng
./configure --prefix=~/apps/proxychains4 --sysconfdir=~/confs
make install

#edit ~/confs/proxychains.conf, add
#socks4     127.0.0.1 1080
#http   127.0.0.1 1080
socks5  127.0.0.1 1080

#make sure only use socks5, change 1080 to your port

#then
~/apps/proxychains4/proxychains4 firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same trouble, when i use the sock5 mode on ss-qt5 on ubuntu.
Here is my solution:
After i change the local port to the same  number of the server port it works.